# how can i find only the full word and not just part of it in regex?

Tags: javascript

how can i use match() method or any other method to find only the full word itself . not just part of it
for example if the user will enter the word sixty it will not execute the if Statements with the match() method ,i want that  only if the user will enter the word six itself it will execute the if statements

```
  var inputNum = prompt("Please enter a number between 50 and 100:");

  if (isNaN(inputNum)) {
  if (inputNum.match(/one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten/)) {
  alert("While this is a number, it's not really a number to me.");
  } else {
  alert(inputNum + " doesn't appear to be a number.");
  }
  }
```

Comment: You can do it by expressing the definition of fullword, e.g. \w+\s

Answer (score 1):

Use test instead like:

var inputNum = "one";

```
let result = /one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten/.test(inputNum);
console.log("one", result);
```

Here is a full demo

```js
   var inputNum = prompt("Please enter a number between 50 and 100:");
let result = /one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten/.test(inputNum);
console.log(inputNum," " ,result);
```

Comment: but i want him to be able to find any one of this words , not just the string "one"

Comment: that is that it is doing

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `^`in the beginning and `$` in the end

- `^` indicates the beginning of the string.
- `$` indicates the end of the string.

This will ensure that your word will exactly match `six` and not `sixty`. If you type `sixty` else block will execute and on typing `six` if block, as you wanted.

```js
 var inputNum = prompt("Please enter a number between 50 and 100:");

  if (isNaN(inputNum)) {
  if (inputNum.match(/^(one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten)$/)) {
  alert("While this is a number, it's not really a number to me.");
  } else {
  alert(inputNum + " doesn't appear to be a number.");
  }
  }
```

Comment: You can upvote the answer and also mark it as accepted by clicking the ✔ icon , if my answer was correct and helpful. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)